# For JS strings, is a.localeCompare(b) === 0 always the same as a === b?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Given two strings, does localeCompare always work the same as triple equals for equality comparison?

Chinese characters and astral characters seem ok

```
function compareEm(a,b) {
    if (a === b != a.localeCompare(b) === 0) {
        console.log(a, b, a === b, a.localeCompare(b))
    }
}

compareEm('\u6f22', "漢") // no output
compareEm('', "\uD83D\uDCA9") // no output
```

Is there a case where this doesn't hold true?
If I change my locale, will it cease to hold true?

Comment: Yes, they should always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.localeCompare(b) === 0` is equivalent to  `a === b`.

`localeCompare` only really becomes interesting when

1. you start paying attention to the sign of the non-zero answers (e.g. `'á'.localeCompare('b')`)
2. or if you add flags, e.g. case-insensitivity.

FYI, `localeCompare` can be inconsistent among browsers for unequal strings.

Comment: Yeah sensitivity flags seems to make them different. Glad to hear that without any flags they are always the same. Thanks